# How can I convert a .txt file into a JavaScript object?

Tags: json

I am just out of bootcamp and not familiar with .jl files. I read a solution on stack overflow to convert the .jl files into .txt and the files look like JSON syntax - but I am not experienced enough to say it absolutely is JSON!

The .txt file looks like this - if I wanted to access this file with FE React.js framework and only the product_id/ price / product_imgs_source - is there a method to do this? I can use the data simply by hard-coding it into an array and using it as front-end data and it works - but I am looking for a method that helps me map through this .txt data so a data-transformation method from .txt to .js

```
{"product_categories_mapped": [24]
  "product_id": "ny221a00q-n11",
  "price": "84.99", 
  "product_title": "some description",
  "product_imgs_src": ["https://some.jpg"],  
  "images": [{"url": "https://some.jpg", 
  "path": "some.jpg", 
  "checksum": "10f6a0dc3db6b15724cebe9b1cb244be"}], 
   }
```

When I used the global fetch() method on the data that was a https link from aws s3 db with a .jl file extension - the error was a 403 so I converted the .jl files to a .txt file and would be great if I could use a JavaScript method to access the .txt data - my worst option is to make it work by manually extracting the data and hardcoding it into an array of objects and accessing the information in the front-end, then creating a node-express environment and a mongo-db collection from this data that I have manually extracted - if there is a better way I will be grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: Your question seems to be about JSON line files with extension ".jl", not about julia files which also have extension ".jl" Someone change the tag? (Edit: Thank you, @crstnbr) See http://jsonlines.org

Comment: Error 403 means “forbidden”, the issue here is likely your s3 bucket is not public so you need to either make it public or authenticate properly when calling fetch().

Comment: I'm not a json expert but maybe .jl means .jsonl (JSON lines)?

Comment: Thanks I did a manual work around 0 the files were not accessible to me so I converted them into JSON